# How can I generate a random alphanumeric string in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I've been trying to write a script that creates a random alpha numeric of 20 letters and attaches it to the end of a link. I'm stuck on making the alphanumeric. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 9):

```clj
(apply str (repeatedly 20 #(rand-nth "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789")))
```

Comment: there is no reason to prefer `reduce str` over `apply str` here. moreover `reduce str` is dramatically slower, since it leads to the creation of multiple obsolete StringBuilder instances, instead of one instance with `apply`. see the [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L544)

Comment: And this? https://cljs.github.io/api/cljs.core/random-uuid